# How to execute SQL query without displaying results in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to execute a SQL query without displaying results. It might cause a faster query. Is it possible?

```
select id
from trips
order by l_pickup <->
(select l_pickup
from trips
where id =605689)
limit 100000
```

This query takes approximately 40 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explain (analyze)` will execute the statement but will not return the results (only the execution plan).

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE):

> With this option, EXPLAIN actually executes the query, and then displays the true row counts and true run time

So you can use:

```
explain (analyze)
select id
from trips
order by l_pickup <-> (select l_pickup
                       from trips
                       where id =605689)
limit 100000;
```

The runtime reported by that is the time on the server without sending the data to the client. It will also show you what the slowest part of the statement is.